# Couldn't map data to datarow cell, data table widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, flutter-datatable

I'm creating a `datawidget`to display some data in table, The data content is in a list, I tried mapping it to rows of `datawidget` but I get this error when I try amountpaid.map

> The argument type 'Iterable' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'

I don't understand the error, what does that mean and how do I solve it.

amountpaidclass

```
class amountPaidClass {
  int amount;
  amountPaidClass({required this.amount});
}

var amountpaid = <amountPaidClass>[
  amountPaidClass(amount: 1000),
  amountPaidClass(amount: 5000),
  amountPaidClass(amount: 7000)
];
```

Displaying data

```
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: DataTable(
                  columns: const [DataColumn(label: Text('Amount'))],
                  rows: amountpaid.map((amountPaidClass) => null)
                  ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out the type of List.map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Iterable/map.html).   It produces an `Iterable`.  So if you want a `List` again, you'll have to do something - in this case, calling `.toList()` on your `Iterable` should do it.

In other words, `amountpaid.map( ... ).toList()`.

Using a good code editor should show you the type of `map` in a hover, which should make this analysis easier.

(As an aside, your code still looks buggy, as you'll be producing a list of. nulls, as you map each item to a null.)